# The ways to speed up controller's response

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a rest service (spring boot) and one of my controller do the following thing: Get request body as json in the following format:

```
{
"type" : "TRERDFDFE43274",
"products" : [
        {
        "code" : "das",
        "reason" : "dasd"

        }...

    ]
}
```

My controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "owner/session",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<ErrorReason>> errorReasons(@Validated @RequestBody Items items) {
    final List<Products> prod = items.getProducts();
    final List<ErrorReason> reasons = new ArrayList<>();
    for(final Products p : prod){
      final ErrorReason r = new ErrorReason();
      r.setReason(p.getReason);
      reasons.add(r);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(reasons);
}
```

As you see a have  DTO class named Items, inside item i have a list of Products
In production the size of Products list is 430 thousands. Controller spend about 4 minutes to make response.
My first option is refactor code to use fork join pool:

```
final List<Products> prod = items.getProducts();
final List<ErrorReason> reasons = new ArrayList<>();
final ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(10);
pool.submit(()->{
   prod.parallelstream().foreach((p)->{
    final ErrorReason r = new ErrorReason();
    r.setReason(p.getReason);
    reasons.add(r);
  })

}).get();

return ResponseEntity.ok(reasons);
```

Now it takes 2 minutes to make response, are there another options to speed up response time?

Answer (score 0):

If you profile your code (which you should always do when you have performance issues), you'll notice that in addition to time going to the creation of the `ErrorReason` objects (which you tried to solve with a `ForkJoinPool`), a lot of the time will consist of converting the `ErrorReason` objects to JSON, i.e. back to text.

A surefire way to improve performance would be to forget the creation of `ErrorReason` objects altogether and just write the raw JSON directly to the response body.

It won't be very pretty, but then again writing 430,000 objects to the response isn't very pretty either. You're guaranteed a huge performance increase because you're no longer doing the unnecessary `text->object->text` transformation.